# dateFormatter returns different dates according to device

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsdateformatter

I have been using the following code to format a date value:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setLocale:[NSLocale systemLocale]];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *myDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"2014-03-06 06:42:21"];
```

Here `myDate` object value is different for different devices. How can I make the `myDate` object value   same, regardless of device.

Comment: Can you please Elaborate your question?

Comment: do you want to get current date ?

Comment: It is because `[NSLocale systemLocale]` are difference in your devices and in your string you didn't give time zone.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the date formatter's locale to the special locale of en_US_POSIX.

```
[dateFormat setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
```

Answer (score -1):

You want to set the `NSTimeZone` and the `NSLocale` manually to ensure the same result.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en"]];
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *myDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"2014-03-06 06:42:21"];
```

Comment: still am getting same result 2013-03-06 09:04:33 AM +0000.

Answer (score -2):

I got the answer when i changed year letters case as follows (yyyy) :

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
```